# EOF encountered inside an action

Tags: lex

im having this error when i run flex on this:

```
%{
    #include "parser.tab.c"
    extern "C" int yylex();
%}

%%

[0-9]+        { yylval.intVal = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER_LITERAL; }
[0-9]+.[0-9]+ { yylval.floatVal = atof(yytext); return FLOAT_LITERAL; }
"+"           { return PLUS; }
"-"           { return MINUS; }
"*"           { return MULT; }
"/"           { return DIV; }
";"           { return SEMI; }
[ \t\r\n\f]   ; /* ignore whitespace */
```

error on line 15

Comment: I can't reproduce that; I pasted it into a file and ran flex on it without any issues. The error message usually means that you have unbalanced braces in an action, or an unterminated comment, or some other similar issue. Please ensure that your actual file is exactly the same as what you copied into the question.

Comment: Note that the declaration of `yylex` inside the lexer source is, at best, redundant. Where it needs to be declared is in translation units which *use* yylex, notably your parser. But that has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @rici https://res.cloudinary.com/dwnf8x8bd/image/upload/v1642028584/erro_cc0mk0.png

Comment: It's impossible to copy and paste from an image, so that's not helpful. Put the file on github. If you don't want to do that, here's a complete guess: You don't have a newline at the end of the file.

Comment: @rici https://github.com/fgsoftware1/fglanguage/blob/master/src/lexer.l

Comment: Yep. The last line is unterminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex requires that the specification file you give it ends with a newline character, and yours doesn't. Your editor should add one automatically; if it doesn't, add a blank line and find a better editor.

According to Posix, text files *must* end with a newline character, and some utility functions -- including flex -- misbehave if they don't.